# Is there a way to specify an HTML5 custom element should be used only once per document?

Tags: html, polymer

I searched around on Google, here on StackOverflow, probably-now-outdated HTML5 spec's, and have not found an answer.  I feel as though I'm missing something obvious.

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify when creating an HTML5 custom element, that users of that new element *should* (or must, to be 'valid' to the element's spec) only use it once per document?

For example with HTML's elements, 'head', 'body', 'main', etc., should only be used once within a document.  I have not been able to find a way to do this with custom elements.  Is this possible, either with vanilla HTML5, Polymer, or some other means?

Thanks to any who can help.

Comment: And, what do you expect to happen if one of these custom elements is used more than once?  Ignored?  Treated as a plain div?  Something else?

Comment: For my cases, I'll probably just ignore the element.  But I suppose it would depend on the element and the consequences of having it occur more than once within the DOM, in the context of the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in callbacks to track the usage of the custom element:

```
var MyElementPrototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
MyElementPrototype.len = 0;
MyElementPrototype.attachedCallback = function() {
  MyElementPrototype.len++;
  if (MyElementPrototype.len > 1) {
    alert('The Document is not Valid'); // Do Something
  }
};
MyElementPrototype.detachedCallback = function() {
  MyElementPrototype.len--;
};
document.registerElement(
  'my-element',
  {
    prototype: MyElementPrototype
  }
);
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, as it does not rely on any particular library, just JS.  I had hoped for something in a manner similar to XML Schema, with minOccurs/maxOccurs (not specifically that, but something along those lines).  But this works all the same, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate the document, you can do it easily with JavaScript.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4AXaS/

**HTML:**

```
<div>Lorem</div>
<div>Ipsum</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    if ($('div').length > 1) {
        alert("Can't use this element more than once in the document");
    }
});
```